# C# bool and bool? jQuery Validate issues

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

There are 2 issues here, both related.

The first issue relates to the use of `[Required] bool?` and jQuery Validate in .NET MVC, where the form is not prevented from posting where no value is present, nor is a warning message displayed when a user modifies the toggle to the middle `null` position (True/null/False).

The second issue relates to the use of `[BooleanRequired] bool` and use of CheckBoxFor with and jQuery Validate in .NET MVC, in that in certain conditions the CheckBox actually disappears. For example in Chrome, if you post the form without ticking the Terms Checkbox the ::before state is removed and therefore the CheckBox disappears, that doesn't happen in IE11 however unticking the CheckBox causes after the warning is displayed does cause the CheckBox to disappear.

The code below for both issues is below:

**HomeController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(Test test)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //return Redirect("/thank-you");
    }

    return View(test);
}
```

**Test.cshtml**

```
<section class="content container">
    <article class="content content__full">
        @Html.Partial("_TestForm")
    </article>
</section>
```

**_TestForm.cshtml**

```
@using WebAppliation1.Helpers
@model WebAppliation1.Models.Test

@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "TestForm", @class = "test-form" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <div id="QuestionDiv">
        <label>Are you a badger?</label>
        @Html.HiddenForExt(model => model.Question, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "required", "required" } })
    </div>

    <footer>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Terms, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "required", "required" } })
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Terms)
        <a href="/terms-and-conditions" target='_Blank'>Terms and Conditions</a>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Terms)
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn" />
    </footer>
}
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jqueryNouisliderAll")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/test")
```

**test.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var question = $("#Question").val();

    question = question === "" ? "1" : question === "True" ? "0" : "2";

    $("#QuestionDiv").toggle({
        selectorName: "QuestionDiv",
        displaySelectedValue: false,
        start: question
    });

    $("#QuestionDiv").on("change", function () {
        question = this.value;

        question = question === "1" ? null : question === "0" ? "True" : "False";

        $("#Question").val(question);
    });
});


$.validator.messages.required = function (param, input) {
    return $(input).data("val-required");
}

$.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function (value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || value !== param;
}, "Please specify a different (non-default) value");

$("#TestForm").validate({
    rules: {
        Question: {
            notEqual: null
        },
        //Question: {
        //    //minlength: 4,
        //    //required: true
        //    required: function(element) {//        
        //        return $("#QuestionDiv").value !== 1;
        //    }
        //},
        Terms: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        Terms: {
            required: "You must accept the terms and conditions"
        },
        Question: {
            minlength: "Please select either Yes or No",
            required: "The Question field is required"
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        var text = error.text();

        if (text.indexOf("required") !== -1) {
            element.attr("placeholder", error.text());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        if ($(element).is("select")) {
            $(element.form).find("select[id=" + element.id + "]").parent().find("span").addClass("error").removeClass("valid");
        } else {
            $(element).addClass("error").removeClass("valid");
        }
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        if ($(element).is("select")) {
            $(element.form).find("select[id=" + element.id + "]").parent().find("span").addClass("valid").removeClass("error");
        } else {
            $(element).addClass("valid").removeClass("error");

            var label = $("label[for='" + element.id + "']").text();

            $(element).prop("placeholder", label);
        }
    },
    focusInvalid: true
});

(function ($) {
    var pluginName = "toggle";

    function plugin(element, options) {
        var toggle = null;

        var leftLabel = null;

        var rightLabel = null;

        var $el = $(element);

        var $toggle = null;

        var $leftLabel = null;

        var $rightLabel = null;

        options = $.extend({}, $.fn[pluginName].defaults, options);

        function render() {
            $el.append("<span class='toggle-slider__option toggle-slider__option-left'>" + options.leftLabelText + "</span>");

            $el.append("<div class='toggle-slider'></div>");

            $el.append("<span class='toggle-slider__option toggle-slider__option-right'>" + options.rightLabelText + "</span>");

            var type = "hidden";

            if (options.displaySelectedValue) {
                type = "text";
            }

            $el.append("<input id='" + options.selectorName + "' name='" + options.selectorName + "' class='toggle-slider-display' type='" + type + "' value='" + options.start + "'></input>");

            toggle = $el.children(".toggle-slider");

            leftLabel = $el.children(".toggle-slider__option-left");

            rightLabel = $el.children(".toggle-slider__option-right");

            $toggle = $(toggle);

            $leftLabel = $(leftLabel);

            $rightLabel = $(rightLabel);
        }

        function configure() {
            $toggle.noUiSlider({
                range: {
                    'min': options.minVal,
                    'max': options.maxVal
                },
                format: options.format,
                start: options.start
            });
        }

        function toggleVal(value) {
            $("#" + options.selectorName).val(value);

            $leftLabel.removeClass("left");

            $rightLabel.removeClass("right");

            $toggle.removeClass("left");

            $toggle.removeClass("right");

            $toggle.removeClass("off");

            switch (value) {
                case "0":
                    $leftLabel.addClass("left");
                    $toggle.addClass("left");
                    break;
                case "2":
                    $rightLabel.addClass("right");
                    $toggle.addClass("right");
                    break;
                default:
                    $toggle.addClass("off");
            }
        }

        function bind() {
            $leftLabel.click(function () {
                $toggle.val(0);
            });

            $rightLabel.click(function () {
                $toggle.val(2);
            });

            $toggle.Link().to(toggleVal);
        }

        function init() {
            render();
            configure();
            bind();
        }

        function destroy() {
            $el.each(function () {
                var $el = $(this);

                hook("onDestroy");

                $el.removeData("plugin_" + pluginName);
            });
        }

        init();

        return {
            destroy: destroy
        };
    }

    $.fn[pluginName] = function (options) {
        if (typeof options === "object" || !options) {
            return this.each(function () {
                if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
                    $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new plugin(this, options));
                }
            });
        }
    };

    $.fn[pluginName].defaults = {
        onInit: function () { },
        onDestroy: function () { },
        step: 1,
        minVal: [0, 1, 2],
        maxVal: 2,
        displaySelectedValue: true,
        start: 1,
        selectorName: pluginName + "Selector",
        format: wNumb({
            decimals: 0
        }),
        leftLabelText: "Yes",
        rightLabelText: "No"
    };
}($));
```

**InputExtender.cs**

```
public static MvcHtmlString HiddenForExt<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes = null, bool readOnly = false)
{
    if (htmlAttributes == null)
    {
        htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    var modelMetadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);

    if (modelMetadata != null) htmlAttributes.Add("id", modelMetadata.PropertyName);

    var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;

    var stringLengthAttribute = memberExpression?.Member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringLengthAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() as StringLengthAttribute;

    if (stringLengthAttribute != null)
    {
        if (htmlAttributes.ContainsKey("maxlength") == false)
        {
            htmlAttributes.Add("maxlength", stringLengthAttribute.MaximumLength);
        }
    }

    return html.HiddenFor(expression, htmlAttributes);
}
```

**Test.cs**

```
public class Test
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Are you a badger? Requires a Yes or No")]
    [Display(Name = "Are you a badger?")]
    public bool? Question { get; set; }

    [BooleanRequired(ErrorMessage = "You must accept the terms and conditions.")]
    [Display(Name = "I agree with the ")]
    public bool Terms { get; set; }
}
```

If it helps I am using jquery-2.1.4.js, jquery.validate-1.17.0.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive-3.2.11.js.

I hope someone can please shed some light as to what I may be doing wrong or how to provide a workaround for these issues.

Comment: Swapping out the `errorPlacement` code addresses the loss of visibility for the CheckBox `errorPlacement: function (error, element) { var text = error.text(); if (text.indexOf("required") !== -1) { element.attr("placeholder", error.text()); } else { if ($(element).is(':checkbox')) { error.insertAfter(element.closest("footer")); } else { error.insertAfter(element); } } }` so that's one issue resolved.

Comment: Since you are using Unobtrusive Validation plugin, you cannot call `.validate()` yourself.  The Unobtrusive plugin constructs and calls the `.validate()` method automatically.  And since the plugin does not allow `.validate()` to be called more than once on the same form, your instance will always be ignored.  If you somehow could force your instance to be used instead, then the Unobtrusive plugin would be completely pointless.

Answer (score 0):

The issues re the hidden fields not being validated is because they are ignored by default, you have to specify if you wish to validate which hidden fields you wish to use. To validate all hidden fields use `ignore: ""`, in my case I used `ignore: ":hidden:not(#Question)"`. The previous use of errorPlacement was causing the CheckBox to disappear.

Below is the modified `test.js` which corrects all of the above issues:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var question = $("#Question").val();

    question = question === "" ? "1" : question === "True" ? "0" : "2";

    $("#QuestionDiv").toggle({
        selectorName: "QuestionDiv",
        displaySelectedValue: false,
        start: question
    });

    $("#QuestionDiv").on("change", function () {
        question = this.value;

        if (question === "1") {
            $("label[for*='Question']").html("Are you a badger? requires either Yes or No");
        } else {
            $("label[for*='Question']").html("Are you a badger?");
        }

        question = question === "1" ? null : question === "0" ? "True" : "False";

        $("#Question").val(question);
    });
});

$.validator.messages.required = function (param, input) {
    return $(input).data("val-required");
}

$("#TestForm").validate({
    ignore: ":hidden:not(#Question)",
    rules: {
        Question: {
            required: function () {
                var questionDiv = $("#QuestionDiv").val();

                if (questionDiv === "1") {
                    $("label[for*='Question']").html("Are you a badger? requires either Yes or No");
                } else {
                    $("label[for*='Question']").html("Are you a badger?");
                }

                return questionDiv === "1" ? true : false;
            }
        },
        Terms: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        Terms: {
            required: "You must accept the terms and conditions"
        },
        Question: {
            required: "The Question field is required"
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        var text = error.text();

        if (text.indexOf("required") !== -1) {
            element.attr("placeholder", error.text());
        } else {
            if ($(element).is(':checkbox')) {
                error.insertAfter(element.closest("footer"));
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        if ($(element).is("select")) {
            $(element.form).find("select[id=" + element.id + "]").parent().find("span").addClass("error").removeClass("valid");
        } else {
            $(element).addClass("error").removeClass("valid");
        }
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        if ($(element).is("select")) {
            $(element.form).find("select[id=" + element.id + "]").parent().find("span").addClass("valid").removeClass("error");
        } else {
            $(element).addClass("valid").removeClass("error");

            var label = $("label[for='" + element.id + "']").text();

            $(element).prop("placeholder", label);
        }
    },
    focusInvalid: false
});

(function ($) {
    var pluginName = "toggle";

    function plugin(element, options) {
        var toggle = null;

        var leftLabel = null;

        var rightLabel = null;

        var $el = $(element);

        var $toggle = null;

        var $leftLabel = null;

        var $rightLabel = null;

        options = $.extend({}, $.fn[pluginName].defaults, options);

        function render() {
            $el.append("<span class='toggle-slider__option toggle-slider__option-left'>" + options.leftLabelText + "</span>");

            $el.append("<div class='toggle-slider'></div>");

            $el.append("<span class='toggle-slider__option toggle-slider__option-right'>" + options.rightLabelText + "</span>");

            var type = "hidden";

            if (options.displaySelectedValue) {
                type = "text";
            }

            $el.append("<input id='" + options.selectorName + "' name='" + options.selectorName + "' class='toggle-slider-display' type='" + type + "' value='" + options.start + "'></input>");

            toggle = $el.children(".toggle-slider");

            leftLabel = $el.children(".toggle-slider__option-left");

            rightLabel = $el.children(".toggle-slider__option-right");

            $toggle = $(toggle);

            $leftLabel = $(leftLabel);

            $rightLabel = $(rightLabel);
        }

        function configure() {
            $toggle.noUiSlider({
                range: {
                    'min': options.minVal,
                    'max': options.maxVal
                },
                format: options.format,
                start: options.start
            });
        }

        function toggleVal(value) {
            $("#" + options.selectorName).val(value);

            $leftLabel.removeClass("left");

            $rightLabel.removeClass("right");

            $toggle.removeClass("left");

            $toggle.removeClass("right");

            $toggle.removeClass("off");

            switch (value) {
                case "0":
                    $leftLabel.addClass("left");
                    $toggle.addClass("left");
                    break;
                case "2":
                    $rightLabel.addClass("right");
                    $toggle.addClass("right");
                    break;
                default:
                    $toggle.addClass("off");
            }
        }

        function bind() {
            $leftLabel.click(function () {
                $toggle.val(0);
            });

            $rightLabel.click(function () {
                $toggle.val(2);
            });

            $toggle.Link().to(toggleVal);
        }

        function init() {
            render();
            configure();
            bind();
        }

        function destroy() {
            $el.each(function () {
                var $el = $(this);

                hook("onDestroy");

                $el.removeData("plugin_" + pluginName);
            });
        }

        init();

        return {
            destroy: destroy
        };
    }

    $.fn[pluginName] = function (options) {
        if (typeof options === "object" || !options) {
            return this.each(function () {
                if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
                    $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new plugin(this, options));
                }
            });
        }
    };

    $.fn[pluginName].defaults = {
        onInit: function () { },
        onDestroy: function () { },
        step: 1,
        minVal: [0, 1, 2],
        maxVal: 2,
        displaySelectedValue: true,
        start: 1,
        selectorName: pluginName + "Selector",
        format: wNumb({
            decimals: 0
        }),
        leftLabelText: "Yes",
        rightLabelText: "No"
    };
}($));
```

I also modified `<label>Are you a badger?</label>` to `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Question)` to correctly target the label in jQuery `$("label[for*='Question']")` with additional code to control the label text when either using form validation or user interaction as even `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Question)` would be hidden because of the use `@Html.HiddenForExt(model => model.Question, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "required", "required" } })`.